# Why is my CGRect not acting the way it should?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cgrect

I have a simple application that I am making, following The Big Nerd Ranch iOS book.

I am getting this peculiar response from a CGRect where it doesn't leave the origin of the simulator no matter what values are entered.

I create a simple UIView class called HypnosisView and it doesn't have any code in it.

Here is the code I am using in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    CGRect firstFrame = CGRectMake(160, 240, 100, 150);

    HypnosisView *firstView = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:firstFrame];
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.window addSubview:firstView];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

And here is what is created:
[image: CGRect not responding]

I am hoping this is another quirk of Xcode 6 and not some silly mistake I have made, however I've been looking at it for a good couple of hours and I'm sick of it.

EDIT: I think I figured out my problem, however it raises a side question.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HypnosisView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGRect frame;

@end
```

This Was the code in my HypnosisView.h file and the superclass obviously has it's own version of **initWithFrame**.

If you don't overwrite the superclass's functions, can they call your instance variables by accident?

For example here we have the example function:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
}
```

Would self ultimately equal the instance variable "frame"? Even though I never called the **initWithFrame** function so the super version should be out of scope?

Comment: Try `firstView.frame=firstFrame;` after `makeKeyAndVisible`.

Comment: That didn't change anything. What were you trying?

Comment: Show code in HypnosisView.h and .m，I just do what you said with my xcode 6,it works well.

Comment: I realized I mistakenly put a property in the .h file when there shouldn't have been that had the same name as the local variable passed into the super class version of initWithFrame.